# Regular expression with calculated field in Google Data Studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have the following calculated field but It doesn't work:

```
sum(CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(url, 'foo') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

My goal is to sum all the url containing the word 'foo'. Does it make sense? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.*foo.*` since [`REGEXP_MATCH` requires a full string match](https://support.google.com/360suite/datastudio/answer/7064476?hl=en):

> `REGEXP_MATCH` attempts to match the entire string contained in *field_expression*.

Use

```
sum(CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(url, '.*foo.*') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                                 ^^   ^^
```

Comment: and If I'm looking for multiple term does `'.*foo.*|.*bar.*'` is supposed to work  ?

Comment: When you have to use alternations, the best practice is that none of them should match at the same location (otherwise, you will have performance issues). So, use `'.*(foo|bar).*'`. If you have `foot`, `foo`, `bar`, `board`, use `'.*(foot?|b(ard|oard)).*'`